# Сериализация с помощью Jackson

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, сериализация, jackson

Изучаю сериализацию с помощью Jackson в Java.
При запуске отладки возникает следующая ошибка:

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature*.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался? В чем может быть проблема?
Использую VS Code. Создал проект в Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что неправильно указана зависимость в файле `pom.xml`, или её версия, [интерфейс `JacksonFeature`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature.html) был добавлен относительно недавно в версии 2.12.

Зависимость в `pom.xml` выглядит так, где `jackson.version` -- любая версия от 2.12.0 (ноябрь 2020) и выше:

```xml
<properties>
<jackson.version>2.12.2</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: К сожалению, проблема так и осталась

Comment: Может имеет смысл предоставить немного больше информации?  Вероятно, у вас существует конфликт версий и подтягивается старая версия `jackson-core`  Проверить версии можно при помощи команды `mvn dependency:tree`, для сохранения этой информации в файл `deps` можно перенаправить вывод:  `mvn dependency:tree > deps`.  Также следует показать свой `pom.xml`

Comment: Да, все верно. Был конфликт версий, чуть ниже в pom.xml стояла версия 2.9.6. Спасибо за помощь!